# I need to get specific data on webpages and put it on excel

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I need a program most probably macro to access the currently open webpage then grab a particular data then paste it on an excel file.

I can't use the web query on excel since the website I need to access is password protected.

I approximately copy paste the data from 100 webpages to 2000 webpages per day.

sample data display on where I need to get from the webpages is as follows:

```
@Serial Code: 123345 ; @Database: DB001 ; @Title: Sample Tile
```

In excel it should be:
|12345| DB001 | Sample Title

So what I need is 
1. Go to the webpage
2. Run the macro to get the data
3. Go to the next webpage

I hope you can help me

Comment: Proving the web page would help an actual approach to be suggested. Especially if a trial account could be used

Answer (score 1):

For most powerful suites, you can use a scripting language with web client, e.g. `perl` or `python`. I've done that with perl.

For the password issue, first submit your login information and save the **cookies**, use the cookies to access password protected content.

Save the page content as text files, parse it to extract the fields.

Comment: This is not an answer that can be implemented, it is a few high level steps.

Answer (score 1):

Sample how to read html from vba:
    Option Explicit

```
' Add References:
' - Microsoft HTML Object Library
' - Microsoft Internet Controls

Private Const URL As String = "C:\temp\Test.html"
Sub Test()

  Dim browser As InternetExplorer
  Set browser = New InternetExplorer

  With browser
    browser.Visible = True
    browser.Navigate URL
    Do: Loop Until browser.Busy = False
  End With

  Dim htmlDocument As htmlDocument
  Set htmlDocument = browser.Document

  ' input
  Dim inputElement As HTMLInputElement
  Set inputElement = htmlDocument.getElementById("input1")

  If (inputElement Is Nothing) Then
    Err.Raise 123456789, , "inputElement is nothing. ID not found."
  End If

  [a1] = inputElement.Value

  browser.Quit
  Set browser = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Enter password: have a look here: http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=973

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware if there is any ready macro to do this work, but you can do this by creating custom application.

1. Get the web page view source one by one
2. Parse the page view source and retrieve the values of @Serial Code, @Database, @Title -- using string operation
3. Dump all data into excel using some plugin.